# How many exchanges to order n numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say I have n integers which are all different, in some random order.  If I can only exchange two integers adjacent to each other, how many exchanges does it take to arrange them in ascending order?  Is there some formula for this?

Comment: Are you looking for the worst-case number of exchanges? Average-case? The number depends on the exact ordering you start with, of course.

Comment: I figured there probably wasn't one (or else I would have learned it that semester I took computer science), but I was hoping there was a formula for how many exchanges it would take.  I now realize that there no way to encode the order, without KNOWING THE ORDER, so such a formula is impossible.  Oh well, I'll have to try something else to prove this theorem about determinants.

Comment: If you do know the order, one simple algorithm is to look at the position of the least element; it will take that many swaps to move it all the way left. Delete the least element from the list, and repeat the above until the list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a bubble sort. It will take less than $n^2$ exchanges.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)